# How do I count the number of times where A happened and B happened with R from a table?

Tags: r

Let's say that the data is

```
A B C
0 1 0
1 1 0   <- here A and B is 1
1 0 0
0 1 1
1 1 1   <- here too
1 1 0   <- and here too
```

I want to count the number of times where both A and B are 1. In this case it is 3. It is very easy with SQL but I have no idea how to do it with [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `df` is your data.frame with columns, `A,B,C`:

```
sum(df$A==1 & df$B==1)
```

Comment: And if your columns contain only 0 or 1, you can also say `sum(df$A & df$B)`, which treats `df$A` and `df$B` as boolean vectors ANDed by `&`.

Answer (score 4):

This does the trick, first create some data:

```
df = data.frame(round(matrix(runif(3*10), 10, 3)))
names(df) = c("A","B","C")
```

and for a solution:

```
sum(rowSums(df[c("A","B")]) == 2)
```

or:

```
sum(apply(df[c("A","B")] == 1, 1, all))
```

**EDIT** (Tyler Rinker):

I was curious about the three approaches considering speed and I figured Pauls first approach would be fastest but was wrong.  On a 10,000 row data set using microbenchmark package (500 iterations):

```
## Unit: microseconds
##       expr       min        lq     median        uq         max neval
##  LOGICAL()   386.725   397.455   412.1495   434.308     710.940   500
##    APPLY() 31225.830 39327.696 42790.0280 46586.137 1169824.066   500
##  ROWSUMS()   460.432   489.588   590.5840   621.373    7884.713   500
```

Comment: feel free to remove my edit but I was curious and thought the info was valuable but didn't have an answer of my own

Comment: @TylerRinker thanks for the nice edit! I'm not surprised the `apply` was rather slow as it uses R loops, while `rowSums` uses (probably) C code.